# Frama-C: how to get the start line number and the location of starting character?

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

Now I have `PdgTypes.Node.stmt`, I just can use:

```
Format.printf "%a"
  Printer.pp_location (Cil_datatype.Stmt.loc PdgTypes.Node.stmt)
```

to print the result like this:

```
mkdir.c:500
```

But I want the result that like this:

```
mkdir.c:500:23
```

It means that the output should contain the location of starting character. What should I do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60550348/124319

Comment: Thank you. But I have seen it, the answer did not mention how to customize the pretty-printer. It's my first time to use frama-c and I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Location` in Frama-C (defined in module `Cil_datatype`, in file `src/kernel_services/ast_queries/cil_datatype.ml`) is a pair of `Position`s (defined in the same file), the start and end position of an AST element.

A `Position` is very similar to an OCaml's [`Lexing.position`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Lexing.html). The only difference is that Lexing's position has a string field `pos_fname`, while Frama-C's position has a `Datatype.Filepath` (defined by Frama-C) field `pos_fpath`.

Both `Location` and `Position` have functions `pretty_debug`, which includes the character number. `Position` also has `pp_with_col`, which prints the column number but in format `%a char %d`, which is different from what you want.

In any case, these functions can serve as inspiration to the one you want.

**Important note**: `pos_cnum` stands for *character* offset (from the start of the file) and not *column* offset, so you need to subtract `pos_bol`, the offset of the beginning of the current line, to get the actual column number of a character: `pos_cnum - pos_bol`.

Here's an example of some code that should be close to what you want (you may need an `open Cil_types` or `open Cil_datatypes` for these to work):

```
let (pos_start, _pos_end) = Cil_datatype.Stmt.loc PdgTypes.Node.stmt in
Format.fprintf fmt "%a:%d:%d"
  Datatype.Filepath.pretty pos_start.Filepath.pos_path
  pos_start.Filepath.pos_lnum
  (pos_start.Filepath.pos_cnum - pos_start.Filepath.pos_bol)
```